# asp:Content and client side scripting

Tags: asp.net, jquery, master-pages, gallery

I'm fixing a customer site designed in ASP.NET, using Master pages. I need to put a jQuery adgallery inserted in a Content page which is linked to the master page.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="cphHeader" runat="server">
<div class="ad-gallery">
</div>       
</asp:Content>
```

Since that Content renders in server-side, the jQuery ad gallery does not work.

What workaround, if available, I can use to insert a jQuery gallery in this Master page placeholder?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be trying to put the  in the Content placeholder intended for the html head element of your master page (this is from the id of the content placeholder).   In a ASP.Net content page typically you have two content placeholders one that is for the head element and one for the body element.  So in the head content placeholder you would put your scripts and other resources in the body content placeholder you would put your html markup such as the div.

For the second part of your question if you use $(document).ready() and wireup your gallery from there you are assured that the DOM elements you are trying to work with will be loaded on the page.

Comment: "Header" refers to the page header (div layout), not <head> element. My place holder is inside a panel (under <body>).

Comment: And sorry, I didn't understand how to 'wireup' my jQuery gallery from $(document).ready().

Comment: how about the registering client side script technique?

Comment: I forgot to instance the gallery!

Comment: sorry took me a bit to get back to that.  I should have been more clear I meant kick off the method that creates the gallery in the $(document).ready().